# Apache rewrite exception for / index but not second and deeper indexes?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to have an exception for...

http ://localhost/

...while rewriting the index of any directories underneath...

http ://localhost/directory1/

http ://localhost/directory2/

By having an empty item below (the first item which is between the characters (| on the third line) it creates an exception for ALL indexes so how can I make the exception NOT apply to the localhost/ itself using this copy of .htaccess?

**http ://localhost/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(|directory2/|directory2/) - [L]
RewriteRule !\.(css|xhtml|xml|zip)$ rewrite.php
```

...and I can not mess with server configuration. Additionally this question is not redirect related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule makes an exception for the root index. Since nothing is between ^ (^ = starts with) and $ ($ = ends with) the requested URI this matches http:// localhost/ exactly. Having [space] index.php (or change the extension to what you want) forces the file to rewrite to itself. It does not appear to loop.

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [RewriteCond](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond) to match your directory, and then apply the RewriteRule to anything that matches.

EDIT: Also, I think your ! line might be causing some problems.  I tested with the [rewrite rule tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) and tweaked my suggested fix to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(directory1|directory2)/
RewriteRule .(css|xhtml|xml|zip)$ - [L]
RewriteRule .* rewrite.php
```

This is generally how I match things -- if you have some things you don't want to process, match them and stop processing rules with the [L] directive, then continue ahead for anything else.

Comment: I tried RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !="/" and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !="" without success.

Comment: I just modified my answer a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: You were close and it helped me get to this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/(admin|blog|forums) so +1 and accepted, thanks!